# Nsis error (integrity check failed) when run AffdexSDK-3.3.0-522-win64

Tags: win64, affdex-sdk

After downloaded affdex-sdk(x86_64) form http://developer.affectiva.com/v3_3/windows/
and ran it, I got a Nsis error (integrity check failed). Seems the size of SDK package(5.6M) is not correctly match the size discripted(29.4).

Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

This issue has been corrected. The Windows SDK can now be downloaded from our standard developer portal page at http://developer.affectiva.com/v3_3/windows, rather than from the Google Drive link above.